# Why onKeyDown or onEditorKeyDown cannot capture "Enter" pressing?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, devexpress, key

I have a custom control MyLookUpEdit, it inherites Devexpress LookUpEdit.

In MyLookUpEdit, I have below method:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
```

I use this custom control (let's call it nameLookUpEdit) on a form. When I tab through the control, I see ProcessDialogKey is called and it focus to next control according to tabIndex.

Now we hope when enter is pressed, our control can behavior exactly the same as tab pressed. I think I should add in MyLookUpEdit one of those methods:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
```

or

```
protected override void OnEditorKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
```

and capture the enter key and hence call the ProcessDialogKey explicitly:

```
{
            if(e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                ProcessDialogKey(Keys.Tab);
            }
            base....
        }
```

But when I test on it, I find when nameLookUpEdit is currently focused, I press enter key, neither onKeyDown nor onEditorKeyDown will be called.

Why this happens?

And what is the correctly way to let enter behavior the same as tab?

Comment: That code can't compile, you have to return something.  You probably return *true* so the OnKeyDown method won't be called.

Comment: Hi Hans, the code compile here. Where do you mean I have to return something? I didn't return anything in onKeyDown or onEditorKeyDown

Comment: It is still very unclear, did you override ProcessDialogKey() or not?

Comment: Yes, I override ProcessDialogKey() as this:

Comment: protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
  {
   if (keyData == Keys.Left || keyData == Keys.Right)
   {
    return false;
   }

   return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try overriding ProcesscmdKey ?

edit: Added the return statement for correctness.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```